# Get the data from colorbox in json format

Tags: jquery, json, colorbox

I am quite new with Jquery and colorobox is particular.
I am using the following to open the colorbox:

```
jQuery().colorbox({
        href: 'http://example.com#oslc-core-postMessage-1.0',
        iframe:true,
        width:"1100px",
        height:"80%"
    });
```

After submitting the info within the colorbox, I am getting the following if I am using an iframe:

```
{"oslc_cm:message":"oslc_cm:create","oslc_cm:results":[{"oslc_cm:label":"TA41071:Test", "rdf:resource":"https://example.com/TA41071"}]}
```

Question is: How can I get json values from the colorbox? Right now the colorbox just stays open, blank, and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get json by doing the following:

```
function createListener()
{
window.addEventListener('message', 
  function (event) {
  try { 
    jQuery().colorbox.close();
    var message = event.data;
    if (message.indexOf("oslc-response:")>-1) {
      message=message.substring(14);
    } else {
      alert('Error. return message should start with "oslc-response:".');
      return;
    }
    handleMessage(message);
  } catch (e) {
     // ignore: access exception when trying to access window name
  }
  }
, false );
}

( function($) 
{
$(document).bind('cbox_load', createListener());        
} ) ( jQuery );
```